# MongoDB find() $eq and $gt not working together

Tags: arrays, mongodb, pymongo

When I am running the below query , $eq on "grade" as 80 and $gt on "mean" as 80. I am getting result with "grade"  85

```
db.Test_Collection.find({"semester":3, "grades.grade": { $eq:80 },"grades.mean": { $gt:80 }},{ "grades.$": 1 })
```

Below is result

> { "_id" : ObjectId("61b9c7fd0855658fad86a10c"), "grades" : [ { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 90, "std" : 5 } ] }

Comment: Does the same array in the full document contain an object with grade=80?

Comment: What is the result you are expecting and why?

Comment: Yes it is there

Comment: Yes it is there > db.Test_Collection.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61b9c7fd0855658fad86a10c"), "semester" : 3, "grades" : [ { "grade" : 80, "mean" : 75, "std" : 8 }, { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 90, "std" : 5 }, { "grade" : 90, "mean" : 85, "std" : 3 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61b9c9450855658fad86a10e"), "semester" : 3, "grades" : [ { "grade" : 92, "mean" : 88, "std" : 8 }, { "grade" : 78, "mean" : 90, "std" : 5 }, { "grade" : 88, "mean" : 85, "std" : 3 } ] } I am expecting { "_id" : ObjectId("61b9c7fd0855658fad86a10c"), "semester" : 3, "grades" : [ { "grade" : 80, "mean" : 75, "std" : 8 }

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your query in this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ESku4rVIFdL). Also i set `mean` to be greater than `70` because your description seem to be mistaken (you search for `mean` greater than `80` but your expectation is `{ "_id" : ObjectId("61b9c7fd0855658fad86a10c"), "semester" : 3, "grades" : [ { "grade" : 80, "mean" : 75, "std" : 8 }`)